# @CacheEvict not evicting any entries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

So I'm trying to implement a caching service using redis in spring.this is The code for the caching service.

```
@Service
public class PermissionCachingService {

    @Autowired
    PermissionRepository permissionRepository;


    @CachePut(value = "Permission", key = "#permission.id")
    public Permission save(Permission permission) {
        return permissionRepository.save(permission);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "Permission", key = "#permission.id")
    void delete(Permission permission) {
        permissionRepository.delete(permission);
    }

}
```

This is the object I'm trying to cache.

```java
@Entity
public class Permission {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    Boolean read = false;

    @NotNull
    Boolean write = false;

    @NotNull
    Boolean update = false;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    Resource resource;


    Long  groupId;

    //construct
    //setters and getters
}
```

the save works fine for both saving/updating. however, the delete is doing nothing to the cache whatsoever. I tried evicting all entries, even hardcoding a key to delete, but it's doing nothing.

I tried using CacheManager, and it cleared the "Permission" cache successfully with the getCache("Permission").clear() method. However, evicting using a key didn't work, even though I used the same key as the one in the save. what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Please [edit] your question to use the provided formatting features instead of "code screenshots" ... (It makes (much) easier to copy&paste;)

Comment: Have you tried ‘cacheManager.getCache(“Permission”).evict(permission.Id);’?

Comment: I would strongly suggest against using `@Cache*` annotations combined with JPA. Instead I strongly suggest to put some time in looking into 2nd level caching of your JPA provider and configure that to use Redis instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete method just wasn't public. After making it public, everything worked as intended.

```java
@CacheEvict(value = "Permission", key = "#permission.id")
    public void delete(Permission permission) {
        permissionRepository.delete(permission);
    }
```